# reordering of unrelated instructions changed the result

Tags: c++

I have some code where some instructions are independant of each other (they don't influence each other). But when I rearrange them, their semantics (meaning) change. Like they influence each other.I don't understand why.

The suspect instruction is `multigraph->push_back(...)` (see markers in the code).

I see two possibilities. Either I don't see how they are connected or the compiler does something wrong.

I didn't find anything similar on stackoverflow (maybe I was using wrong keywords).

Please, tell me why this is happening.

You'll find the code below.
I expect that after examining the edge [0 3] the degree of vertex 0 is 0 i.e.
`edge [0 3] 
     → vertex 0 is a leaf 
          -degrees: {0:0} ...`

Here is the code (I extracted just the important part).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<pair<int, int> >::iterator edgeIt;

vector<pair<int, int> >* some_fun() {
    vector<pair<int, int> >* result = new vector<pair<int, int> >();
    result->push_back(make_pair(0, 3));
    result->push_back(make_pair(1, 2));
    result->push_back(make_pair(1, 4));
    result->push_back(make_pair(2, 5));
    result->push_back(make_pair(3, 5));
    result->push_back(make_pair(3, 8));
    result->push_back(make_pair(5, 6));
    result->push_back(make_pair(6, 7));
    return result;
}

const int n = 9;
int degree[n];

int main() {
        vector<pair<int, int> >* multigraph = some_fun();
        sort(multigraph->begin(), multigraph->end());

        /// vertices' degrees
        int degree[n];
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; degree[i++]=0);
        for (edgeIt it=multigraph->begin() ; it!=multigraph->end() ; it++){
            degree[it->first]++;
            degree[it->second]++;
        }

        cerr << "   degrees: ";
        for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
            cerr << "{" << i << ":" << degree[i] << "} ";
        cerr << endl;

        /// double edges for leaves
        vector<int> leaves;
        int mstSize = multigraph->size();
        for (int i=0 ; i<mstSize ; i++) {
            pair<int, int>* el = &(*multigraph)[i];
            cerr << "   edge [" << el->first << " " << el->second << "] \n";
            if (degree[el->first]==1) {
                cerr << "     → vertex " << el->first << " is a leaf \n";
                // here it will not work
                // multigraph->push_back(make_pair(el->first, el->second));
                degree[el->first]=0;
                degree[el->second]++;
                // but here it's OK
                multigraph->push_back(make_pair(el->first, el->second));
                leaves.push_back(el->first);
            }
            else if (degree[el->second]==1) {
                cerr << "     →→ vertex " << el->second << " is a leaf \n";
                degree[el->first]++;
                degree[el->second]=0;
                multigraph->push_back(make_pair(el->first, el->second));
                leaves.push_back(el->second);
            }

            cerr << "\t      -degrees: ";
            for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
                cerr << "{" << i << ":" << degree[i] << "} ";
            cerr << endl;
        }

        cerr << "    *leaves: ";
        for (int i=0 ; i<leaves.size() ; ++i)
            cerr << leaves[i] << " ";
        cerr << endl;

        delete multigraph;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what change (swap) is changing the output ? Also note that you have a memory leak (the vector is never freed)

Comment: In 99.99999% of the cases it is the user's error. If it fails with *no* optimization too, add 3 nines. If another compiler agrees, 4 more. Trace through your code carefully, step by step. Run your program under a debugger, and check each step what is happening.

Comment: @Synxis I emphasized more the swap part. The memory leak is irrelevant in this snippet but thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: @vonbrand My experience also shows me that it's "always" user's error. Thanks for the debugger hint, I think it led me to the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit.
What happens if the vector grows? It can reallocate its contents so `el` will no longer point to the i-th element of the vector, it will point to some location in memory whose meaning is unknown.

The instruction

```
pair<int, int>* el = &(*multigraph)[i];
```

is dangerous. It takes the address of an element in a vector.
The `push_back` instruction triggered a reallocation so calling `el->first` *after* it was no longer correct.
Reading the values from under `el` *before* making changes to the vector fixed the issue.